# Angularjs Hide Show Clean coding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Hey guys I wonder if there's a solution on this mess I normally create in Angular projects:

```
app.controller('indexController', function ($scope) {
    scope.hideWinkelContainer = true;
    scope.hideWinkelPaneel = true;
    scope.headerCart = false;
    scope.showCart = function () {
        scope.hideWinkelContainer = false;
        scope.hideWinkelPaneel = false;
    };
    scope.hideCart = function () {
        scope.hideWinkelContainer = true;
        scope.hideWinkelPaneel = true;
    };
});
```

html:

```
<div class="containerWinkelwagen" ng-hide="hideWinkelContainer"> <div class="winkelWagenPaneel" ng-hide="hideWinkelPaneel">
    <div class="winkelWagenTerug" ng-click="hideCart()"></div>
    <div class="winkelWagenTerug" ng-click="showCart()"></div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Best practices, tips, examples are always welcome!

Comment: What is wrong with what you have written ? Are you looking for some optimisation ? Don't forget to keep it simple for maintainability (lel angular maintainability)!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a `toggle` function as follow:

```
app.controller('indexController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.hideWinkelContainer = true;
    $scope.hideWinkelPaneel = true;
    $scope.headerCart = false;

    $scope.toggleCart = function () {
        $scope.hideWinkelContainer = !$scope.hideWinkelContainer;
        $scope.hideWinkelPaneel    = !$scope.hideWinkelPaneel;
    };
});
```

In your HTML:

```
<div class="containerWinkelwagen" ng-hide="hideWinkelContainer">
    <div class="winkelWagenPaneel" ng-hide="hideWinkelPaneel">
        <div class="winkelWagenTerug" ng-click="toggleCart()"></div>
        <div class="winkelWagenTerug" ng-click="toggleCart()"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the show/hide functions once in a factory, and then inject it into the controllers that need it. Saves a lot of boilerplate.